# Need help injecting SSID into Momentum app checking for device wifi

Tags: android

## Hello so I'm trying to add a device onto my Genymotion emulated device

### but to add it the app needs to detect the AP. this is the logcat of just the apps logs

If anyone can help let me know im trying to find how to inject that the SSID was matched.

Comment: Sorry but from my perspective this question is only a confusing collection of sentences that don't fit together. Please edit and write in detail what you are planning, what you have and what your problem(s) are. And please remove the strange text formatting.